# Spring Tool Suite embedded server won't start after windows 8.1 upgrade

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-8.1, spring-tool-suite

A strange thing has happened and it seems like it was triggered by the latest Windows upgrade.  I upgraded from Windows 8.0 to 8.1, and ever since then, the embedded tomcat server in Spring Tool Suite won't start.

There's no indication of any problems in the log/console output, and the console says that it started up normally, but in the servers tab it says that the server is still in "starting..." status (seen below).

[image]

After 120 seconds I get the following dialog:

`Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 120 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.`

I tried running the Tomcat server from a command prompt and it works fine.  I can start the server and deploy my app fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well... after about a week the problem seems to have disappeared on its own.  I wish I could explain what fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

just Double Click on Server it will open one window and click on time outs and give 300 seconds and try it.  it will started thats for sure .

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple , You need to double click on your server. It will open server editor window where you can edit the default start time of server. For reference I am going to attach here screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to change file permissions. For example, if the server is stored in C:\SpringToolSuite\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE, (For Windows 7) Double click in C:\SpringToolSuite\ < Properties < Security. Then change the permissions to "Total Control".